# Infopath 2010, do not show form as preview in email

Tags: infopath2010

On my forms I have a button to send the form to the next person for approval and stuff.
One thing we find very annoying is the preview in the email.
It only leaves a small text area for emailing in case of forwarding or replying.

In Infopath 2003 you only got an attachment you could click on to open the form, but if needed you could reply or forward the email as a regular email with all the space you need for the content.

In the Advance form options there is a section E-Mail Attachements and I switched off the tickbox "always send the current view...".
But still I get the email with the view in it.
Also opening the email will open the form now.

How can I switch these features off in Infopath 2010?

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

found my answer.

On the Advanced options screen, in the section Email attachements, I also switched off the option at the bottom "Enable Infopath email form functionality for this form template"

Now I have an email with the view, but shown as an image and I can write as much text above it as I want to.